# Sort text containing numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a column with string like this:

| column name |
| --- |
| 14 / 21 / 28 days |
| 28 / 35 / 42 days |
| 30 / 60 / 90 days |
| 7 days |

I'm trying to sort them, like this

```
SELECT column_name FROM mytable ORDER BY column_name
```

but without success

I would like a way to order them like this on SQL Server

| column name |
| --- |
| 7 days |
| 14 / 21 / 28 days |
| 21 / 30 / 60 days |
| 28 / 35 / 42 days |
| 30 / 60 / 90 days |

Comment: You should give serious consideration to storing each of the 3 numbers in a separate column.

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server? That backticks look more like MySQL, which is a completely different product.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are sorting strings. So basically it will look at the first character and sort it by ASCII position.

One way to achieve your desired results is to remove the text part and keep only the numbers. Then cast this to integer and then you can use this to sort upon.

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`name`, 'days', ''), ' ',''), '/', '') AS INT) ASC
```